# Theme Live Preview on Front End?

Tags: previews

I have a membership site where a member will fill out a form (FormidablePro, if that matters).  This form contains information that will be the content on a site which will be created once the form is submitted automatically (how that happens isn't my question).

Here's the question: On the form, a list of possible themes is offered up to the member.  Is it possible, similar to what is happening on the WordPress backend, to present a live preview of the theme using the information captured in the form?

Outlandish, I know.  :-)  Thank you!

P.S.  I'm not referring to the Theme Switcher Reloaded functionality.

Comment: [As a google search brought up multiple possible solutions](https://www.google.at/search?q=wordpress+theme+preview+plugin&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): Which one did you already test and which didn't work for you? Sidenote: As plugin recommendations are - here on WPSE - considered [»shopping questions«](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) - what is your actual question? Do you want to write a plugin on your own? Where exactly do you need help?